# fontspec \setmainfont overrides other font families

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

It seems that the use of `fontspec`'s `\setmainfont` is overriding other font families. Is that the expected behavior?

Should I use instead `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`?

A MWE follows below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\setmainfont{Arial}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Font list}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Main font:  \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}
    \item {\rmfamily Roman font: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}}
    \item {\sffamily Sans font: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}}
    \item {\ttfamily TT font: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way it is designed to work. `\setmainfont` essentially just sets the `\rmfamily`.  So if you are explicitly setting the Roman font, there's no need to use `\setmainfont` at all. So in your example, you first set the `\rmfamily` to Times New Roman, and then with `\setmainfont` you set it to Arial.

So if you want Times, Arial and Courier as your fonts you can just use:

```
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
```

Or

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
```

There is really no practical distinction between `\setmainfont` and `\setromanfont`.

Comment: and after that how do I set the default family to Sans Serif? Should I use `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`?

Comment: @AlanMunn `\show\familydefault` ....

Comment: @Lin set `\familydefault` as you show in your question.